# Good reference for representations of the symmetic group $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, permutations, representation-theory

I would like to know what are good and detailed references for representations of the symmetric group $S_n$ over $\mathbb C$. This could be either a book or an article of some notes.

Comment: This depends a lot of what aspects you want to focus on. Do you want the more theoretic aspects, the algorithmic ones? Should it include for instance Schur-Weyl duality, plethysms?

Comment: I am interested more in theoretic aspects, but very basic ones. For example I want a clean, pedagogical  exposition of the fact that to each young diagram one can associate an irreducible representation of $S_n$.

Answer (score 4):

A quite comprehensive study of this is The Symmetric Group: Representations, Combinatorial Algorithms, and Symmetric Functions by Bruce E. Sagan.
As the title suggests, the main focus is on doing computations, but it also covers quite a bit of theory.

An alternative, which is much more theoretical and more general is Characters of Finite Coxeter Groups and Iwahori-Hecke Algebras by Geck and Pfeiffer.
This goes over much of the same theory, but with the general setting of a finite Coxeter group rather than specifically the symmetric group.

Answer (score 3):

G.D. James The Representation Theory of the Symmetric Groups, see here https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0067708